# Automatic Typewriter effect in React Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, css-animations

I want to apply such a [Typewriting](https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/bGvRaGp) effect, I am still struggling with styled components.

I know that I need to define two animations, one for typing to animate the characters and second to blink to animate the caret.

Then I apply the `:after` pseudo-element inline to add the caret to the container element. With Javascript I can set the text for the inner element and set the --characters variable containing the character count. This variable is used to animate the text.

`Wite-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` are needed to make content invisible as necessary.
But its not working in my App. I declared all styles and apply them inline.

`App.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

const styles = {
    typewriterEffect: {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        fontFamily: "monospace",
      },
      
      "typewriter-effect > text": {
        maxWidth: 0,
        animation: "typing 3s steps(var(--characters)) infinite",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        overflow: "hidden",
      },
      
      "typewriter-effect:after": {
        content: " |",
        animation: "blink 1s infinite",
        animationTimingFunction: "step-end",
      },
      
      "@keyframes typing": {
        "75%",
        "100%": {
          maxWidth: "calc(var(--characters) * 1ch)",
        },
      },
      
      "@keyframes blink": {
        "0%",
        "75%",
        "100%": {
          opacity: 1,
        },
        "25%": {
          opacity: 0,
        }
      }
};

function Typewriter() {
    const typeWriter: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('typewriter-text');
    const text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
    
    typeWriter.innerHTML = text;
    typeWriter.style.setProperty('--characters', text.length);

    return (
        <Box style={styles.typewriterEffect}> 
            <Box class="text" id="typewriter-text"></Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export {Typewriter};
```

Comment: You styled object is not a valid object.

Comment: If it's not a big deal, you could use a [library](https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs) for that

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-dhexpe?file=pages/index.js) is a code in js. Is this what you want? @Figario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forked into your codesandbox to recreate your issue.
You could have used `styled-components` i.e

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

given from `MUI` to create styles same as Codepen Example.

**Below is my solution -**

https://codesandbox.io/s/automatic-typewriter-effect-stackoverflow-y546o7?file=/src/Typewriter.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I did this writing a small custom hook

```
export const useTypeWriter = (content = '') => {
    const [prevContent, setPrevContent] = useState(content);
    const [animatedContent, setAnimatedContent] = useState('');
    const hasContentChanged = prevContent === content;

    const generateContent = () => {
        setAnimatedContent((prevAnimatedContent) => {
            const charCount = prevAnimatedContent.length;
            if (prevAnimatedContent.length + 1 !== content.length) setTimeout(generateContent, 90);

            return prevAnimatedContent + content[charCount];
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!hasContentChanged) return;

        setPrevContent(content);
        generateContent(content);
    }, [hasContentChanged]);

    return animatedContent;
};
```

usage:

```
const typeWriterContent = useTypeWriter('Entire content')
return (<div>{typeWriterContent}</div>)
```